# Old gdb cannot find out how to do logging

Tags: linux, command-line, logging, debug, gdb

I'm running an obsolete Red Hat OS and debugging with the built-in gdb but I cannot figure out how to do logging.

I've tried:

```
set logging on
```

But get:

```
No symbol "logging" in current context
```

It also does not show logging option in "set help"

The gdb version is:

```
GNU gdb Red Hat Linux 7.x (5.0rh-15) (MI_OUT)
```

Is there some other way to pipe output to a file?

Comment: Have you checked `man gdb`? If all you want is to log your terminal session, check out `screen`.